# Using Heroku with Cyrillic user folder in Windows

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, cyrillic

This is quite specific problem: developer's machine with Win 7 Ulttimate has cyrillic user folder name, which cannot be changed due to the plenty of another programs rely on this path.

Need to deploy php-app on Heroku.

Using the Heroku toolbeit on this computer, I found while "heroku create" the follow error - "...no such file or directory open...".

By the simple experiment, I found that problem is in cyrillic name of user folder. Undeк another user's account is OK. So, question - is there any case to tune the Heroku fot correct work with such cyrilic enviroment ?

Answer (score 1):

A fix for cyrillic characters in usernames has been pushed to https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ specifically for this problem.  Please run the installer again and retry the `heroku create` command.  It should work starting with heroku/toolbelt/3.42.25 (version information is available from `heroku version`)